# How to generate burst of images from a single image by adding misalignment?

Tags: python, image, pytorch

I'm learning about image denoising and Pytorch.I want to get burst of images generated from a single image. For example, I have an image, then random crop a patch of specific size from it. Then I want to add an 1 or 2 pixels shift on it to get a new image with tiny difference. What could I do? Is it better to use some techniques in PIL or others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Augmentation in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677788/data-augmentation-in-pytorch)

Comment: I have thought about it, but it seemed difficult to restrict the misalignment to 1 or 2 pixels. In other words, I want the first crop place to be random but next crops near the first one. I don't know how augmentation in Pytorch to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `transforms` to do some image augmentation for your problem.

As I read your comment, you can restrict `translate = (a, b)` to do some tiny random shifts in both dimensions.

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform = transforms.RandomAffine(degrees, translate=None, scale=None, shear=None, resample=False, fillcolor=0)

img = PIL.Image.open('path/img')

new_img = transform(img)
```

If you want to perform more transforms like `Crop` as well, group all the `transform` into one big `transform` using `transforms.Compose`. Here is your [reference](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html?highlight=transforms)

Comment: I cannot restrict translate = (2, 2). It rises an error "valueError should be between 0 and 1"

Comment: I just edit the answer (my mistake) to `translate = (a, b)` as the doc indicates `-img_width * a < dx < img_width * a`. So you can compute `a = some value` to match `dx = 2 pixels`, same for `dy`.

Comment: I am confused why the a, b should be multipled with img_width or height. If -img_width < dx < img_width, the image will be shifted beyond the original place?then left a whole black or white image?  Anyway, I finally use PIL to achieve this, and after get these images data, i will transform it to tensor. Thank you anyway !